# How can I store or use a keyboard equivalent from a struct

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu

I have a struct that contains a menu information for a button.  The modifier key can of course be nil as not all menu items have keyboard equivalents.

```
struct MenuInfo {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var tool: Tools
    var modifier: String?
}
```

I have array of menuInfo objects.  I then use a for statement to load

```
ForEach(engToolbar, id: \.name) { (curMenu) in
    Button(curMenu.name, systemImage: curMenu.image)
        { setTool( curMenu.tool ) }
        .background(getBGColor( curMenu.tool))
        .keyboardShortcut( curMenu.modifier, modifiers: .control )
}
```

When I have called it like above I this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'KeyEquivalent'

I tried calling it like this and I don't get an error:

```
.keyboardShortcut( "c", modifiers: .control )
```

Gosh that "c" looks like a string to me :).  Of course everything can't have the same shortcut.  I tried specifying modifier as a KeyEquivalent:

```
var modifier: KeyEquivalent?
```

Then I was told that the modifier var is required to be unbound (I can't have a nil key equivalent.  So... I moved modifier back to a string.  I then tried to cast to a KeyEquivalent:

```
.keyboardShortcut(( KeyEquivalent)curMenu.modifier, modifiers: .control )
```

I get this error:

> Expected ',' separator

So yeah I don't know what to do to solve this issue.

In the long wrong I feel I'll need to do something like:

```
.keyboardShortcut( curMenu.modifier != nil ? (KeyEquivalent)curMenu.modifier : nil, modifiers: .control)
```

Comment: It would seem you only want to apply `.keyboardShortcut` if `curMenu.modifier` isn't `nil`. In other words, if there's no modifier, there's no shortcut to apply.

Comment: @HangarRash I believe that is what I'm doing in the very last line but I get this error: Expected ':' after '? ...' in ternary expression.  Which well there is one.

Comment: You can't use an Objective-C type cast in Swift. That's not the correct syntax. But the bigger issue is that you can't pass `nil` to the first parameter of `.keyboardShortcut`.

Comment: @HangarRash OK, sorry I'm about 8 hours into Swift development.  When using color I noticed that there was something like Color.clear for no color.  I didn't find something like that in KeyEquivalent.  I'll try using an empty string ""  Instead.

Comment: @HangarRash I tried,  wrapping the .keyboardShortcut() in an if statement and I get a conformance error.  I tried to put an empty string in the array and I get can't convert to must be a KeyEquivalent error.  I changed the struct to store a KeyEquivalent and then got additional "" cannot be converted to KeyEquivalent error messages.  I'm so out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter in `.keyboardShortcut(..)` is a `KeyEquivalent`.
When you use for example "c", it is converted to `Character` for use in
a `KeyEquivalent` that expect to have a `Character`, not a `String`.

So you could try this approach, using `var modifier: Character?` in your `MenuInfo`,
and

```
  .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(curMenu.modifier ?? "c"), modifiers: .control)
```

Adjust the default "c" in the example to what you want to do when `curMenu.modifier` is `nil`.

If you make `var modifier: Character`, then you can use

```
.keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(curMenu.modifier), modifiers: .control)
```

EDIT-1:

Here is my test code, tested on MacOS 14.4:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct MenuInfo {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var modifier: Character?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let curMenu = MenuInfo(name: "xxx", image: "yyy", modifier: "x")
    // let curMenu = MenuInfo(name: "xxx", image: "yyy", modifier: nil) // <-- for testing
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { print("-----> action performed") }) {
                Text("Click me")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(curMenu.modifier ?? "c"), modifiers: .control)
        }
        .padding(40)
    }
}
```

EDIT-2:

If you want to have no modifier when `var modifier: Character?` in `nil`,
then use a bit more code with `@ViewBuilder`, such as:

```
struct MenuInfo {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var modifier: Character?  // <--- here can be nil
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let curMenu = MenuInfo(name: "xxx", image: "yyy", modifier: "x") // try nil
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func kbButton() -> some View {
        Group {
            if curMenu.modifier == nil {
                Button(action: { print("-----> NO modifier") }) {
                    Text("Click me")
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: { print("-----> WITH modifier") }) {
                    Text("Click me")
                }.keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(curMenu.modifier!), modifiers: .control)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            kbButton()  // <--- here
        }
        .padding(40)
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually get an error that says Cannot convert value of type 'Character' to expected argument type 'KeyEquivalent'

Comment: updated my answer with the fully working code, tested on MacOS 14.4. What system are you using?

Comment: why did you get an error before

Comment: Did you have `KeyEquivalent` inside `.keyboardShortcut`?  I didn't see it.  Sorry...

Comment: yes I did, makes no sense to have it outside.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This is terrific TY.  I've created a modified version of this answer and merged it into my code removing about 150 lines of code and making this more efficient to create new toolbars, menus etc in the future.  TY so much.

Comment: if my answer helped, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green, thank you.

Comment: Edit 2 of this answer resolved the issue for me.  Store the character as a Character? and at the call wrap it in KeyEquivalent().