# How can I fix Text("").toolbar causing dead space at the top of my content space

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I have a Toolbar View that is causing an issue.  The call to
Text( "" ).toolbar is placing adding dead space at the top of
the content window space.  I have tried substituting Text()
with other items (form, scrollingView etc.) but they are not
the GUI I want.  Gosh I don't want the Text Object but that
seams required for .toolbar to work.  It looks like this:

[image]

The toolbar is supposed to show up in the titlebar of the window, which it does.

I can't figure out what I've done wrong here. Uncommenting
the .borders show a tight wrapper around those objects.
Adding ABC as the text shows the dead space at the top
with ABC centered on the screen.  This of course is a
simplified version of my code.

```
struct ToolbarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text( "" )
              .toolbar
            {
                Button( "Hi!", systemImage: "rectangle" )
            }   // End of toolbar
            .border(Color.purple)   
        }   // End of Stack
    }
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {  
    var body: some View {
        ToolbarView( )
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Group {
                    Text( "For Content" )
                }
                .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity ) // required to fill space
                .background(Color.white)
//              .border(Color.blue, width: 4)

                Group {
                    Text( "My panel" )
                }
                .frame( width: 300 )
                .background( .black )
                .animation(.easeInOut( duration: 0.5 )) // TODO: Update this
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
//              .border(Color.pink, width: 4)
            }

        }
    }
}

struct MyCADApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView( )
                .frame( minWidth: 1000, minHeight: 600 )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does setting the font size of `Text` in the toolbar to zero help ? Or perhaps the height of the frame to 0 ? It would be helpful to also add some screenshots of what you see, where the problem lies and what you expect as I run this at my end and it is not so clear what the issue is.

Comment: @ShawnFrank.  I added a picture.  Changing the font height did not resolve the issue trying Workingdogs idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing your `Text( "" )` with `VStack{}`, works for me.

Comment: TY WD!!  That solved it for me.  I actually went to chat bot and it didn't even suggest using a VStack.  I only have that couple of pixels in the middle of both the content area and the panel and I 'think' I know what that is.  I added padding possibly in the wrong spot.

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to also check your previous question's answers/comments.

Comment: The font styles question?  Yes I did... the issue still persists.  The menu is correct for the default font on launch but won't update.  Bindings didn't work.  I went back to @ ObservedObject and guaranteed that every single View that I have created uses @ ObservedObject.  I did create several Pen Thickness Sliders based on the same variable, one in my RightPanelView and one in my toolbar view and the variable in the model was updated.  Changing one view updated the other view.  So still not sure what happened but will try again in a day or two.

Comment: There is also the other one at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105150/how-can-i-store-or-use-a-keyboard-equivalent-from-a-struct